# Are there monic FSP polynomials of degree 3 that are not built from FSP polynomials of degree 1 or 2?

Tags: number-theory

Are there monic FSP polynomials of degree 3 that are not built from FSP polynomials of degree 1 or 2?

FSP occurs when you mutiply each variable's exponent by 2.

For example, x^2 turns into x^4, and x^2-1 turns into x^4-1.

Comment: What does FSP stand for?

Comment: Factor-square property

Comment: I never heard of this. What’s the definition?

Comment: There's no formal definition, but you double each variable's exponent.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this, Lubin? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me as if your ideas are still in a preliminary state. What does “built from” mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the polynomials of degree 3, we can see that several of them are built from smaller polynomials with FSP of degree 1 or 2.

For example, x^3-1 divides x^6-1, showing that it has FSP. However, x^3-1 is "built from" (x-1)(x^2+x+1). Both x-1 and x^2+x+1 have FSP, as x-1 divides x^2-1 and x^2+x+1 divides x^4+x^2+1.

Likewise, the same method can be shown for x^3-x^2, which divides x^6-x^4. This polynomial is built from x^2(x-1), and both x^2 and x-1 have FSP.

"Built from" simply means that the polynomial of degree 3 can be expressed as two or more polynomials multiplied together.

Comment: I'd suggest that you read this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so that other people can understand your post more easily.